# Kubernetes stateful sets storage in AWS EBM with Helm

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, helm3

I am deploying a stateful set with Helm and the pods are complaining about volumes.

What is the proper way of doing this with AWS EBS? Considering the Helm templates.

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  30s (x112 over 116m)  default-scheduler  0/9 nodes are available: 9 pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims.
```

deployment.yaml

```
volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: {{ .Values.storage.name }}
      labels:
        app: {{ template "etcd.name" . }}
        chart: {{ .Chart.Name }}-{{ .Chart.Version }}
        release: {{ .Release.Name }}
        heritage: {{ .Release.Service }}
    spec:
      storageClassName: {{ .Values.storage.class | default .Values.global.storage.class }}
      accessModes:
        - {{ .Values.storage.accessMode }}
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: {{ .Values.storage.size }}
```

values.yaml

```
storage:
  name: etcd-data
  mountPath: /somepath/etcd
  class: "default"
  size: 1Gi
  accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change the class name to the default name on EKS:

```
...
spec:
  storageClassName: {{ .Values.storage.class | default "gp2" | quote }}
  accessModes:
  - ...


storage:
  ...
  class: "gp2"
  ...
```

Comment: I'll test that. Would I need to create a separate PersistentVolume as well?

Comment: No. In this case PersistentVolume will be dynamically provision.

Comment: Now it's throwing: parse error at (etcd/templates/deployment.yml:179): function "gp2" not defined.

Comment: This is a helm syntax error. See the updated answer.